# How can I place a footnote in my reference?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

One of my references has a typographical error in its title.

http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2017/06/creating-a-reference-for-a-work-published-with-a-typo-in-the-title.html provides guidance in this situation:

> If the article title really included a typo, explain in a footnote, if you want to ensure that your readers know that the mistake is not yours.

The blog post goes on to supply an example, where the title of the reference has a footnote mark with the corresponding text: "The published article includes this typo.".

`notes2bib` does not address this issue, as I am not looking to add an additional reference here.

How can I create such a footnote with biblatex?  I am using the biber backend, if that matters.

Comment: Could you please provide us a minimal code without the footnote feature? I have some ideas for the solution but I need to know the exact style for bibliography and other details you are following.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\mkbibfootnote` macro in the `title` field of your bib entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Linn1968,
  author = {Linn, L.},
  date = {1968},
  title = {Social identification and the seeking of pyschiatric\mkbibfootnote{The published article includes this typo.} care.},
  journaltitle = {American Journal of Orthopsychiatry},
  volume = {38},
  pages = {83-88},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1939-0025.1968.tb00558.x}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think that we can use the `note` field in bibliography for footnote.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @Article{art2017,
    author =     {John Doe and Jane Doe},
    title =      {Paper Title with Typo},
    journal =    {Journal Name},
    year =   {2017},
    note =   {\footnote{There is a typo in the paper title.}}}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\bigskip

We really need to cite this~\cite{art2017}.

\bigskip

\lipsum[3-4]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Using a separate field is nice. You could remove the space before the footnote mark using `\unspace` without side effects (I think). e.g., `note =  {\unspace\footnote{There is a typo in the paper title.}}`

Comment: Another option to match the webpage of the OP is to use `\mkbibfootnote` in the title field itself: `title = {Paper Title wtih\mkbibfootnote{There is a typo in the paper title.} Typo}`

Comment: @DavidPurton Thanks, this is one command I was not aware of.

Comment: @DavidPurton your `\mkbibfootnote` was exactly what I needed.  If you write up your MWE to support it, I will mark it as correct.